# Unable to determine why composer install is failing

Tags: composer-php, docker-compose

I'm unable to determine why composer is failing in [this ci build](https://travis-ci.org/bkuhl/game-watcher/builds/146918679#L1254).  It simply fails the build with no indication as to what the problem was.  I've looked into `-v` to increase the verbosity and that has the same output at the end.

What should I try to debug this?

Comment: Would it be possible to provide the composer.json file aswell?
Couldn't it be some kind of out-of-memory exception?
You might be interested by this thread aswell : https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3379

Comment: Bingo, that was it.  Please post an answer so I can give you credit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composer will fail if its reaches a memory limit.

This seems to be a current trouble being discussed by the composer contributors...

You can find some issues about it on [GitHub](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues?q=memory).

To face this problem, you have different solutions to try :

- `docker exec -it $(docker-compose ps -q sh -c cli) composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist`

If it doesn't seem to come from docker, try to see if your PHP configuration is fine :

- Ensure PHP's `xdebug` extension is disabled for the PHP command-line version
- Check if your `composer.lock` file is commited (it should!)
- run composer with options `-vvv --profile` to know a bit more about the problem
- As recommended by some composer contributors, get started with [PHP-HHVM](http://hhvm.com/)

If any of this is not enough, and you cannot fix it even knowing what is the memory-leak cause with `-vvv` option, well then maybe check either your PHP's memory_limit option or system RAM option, if it is possible for you (but it is still kind of a non-solution in my opinion) :

- Maybe extend the system's memory allowed (swap file or alternatives)
- Maybe install more RAM memory on the machine (worst solution in my opinion)

Comment: It was actually the `sh -c "[COMMAND]"` that resolved the issue.

Comment: Oh okay, I am not really into docker yet :)